# Swift Parse - loading objects immediately after app starts - automatically refreshing

Tags: swift, parse-platform, refresh

```
override func objectsDidLoad(error: NSError!) {
    [super.objectsDidLoad(nil)]

    self.loadObjects()

    //self.queryForTable().cancel()

}
```

So I've been using this function in order to load all the objects in the tableView as soon as the objects have been loaded from Parse. My only problem is that the application doesn't stop loading the objects. The app eventually is trying to constantly refresh that all functionality goes down the toilet. Essentially I need some code that will manually call Parse to refresh my code as soon as the objects have loaded.

Comment: Please explain "need some code that will manually call Parse to refresh my code".

Comment: Ok so I have an asynchronous call to parse to fetch the data and when the tableviewcontroller loads up it loads no objects because none have been called UNLESS they've been cached. I'm basically looking for a method that will load the objects after the query has been called. Some callback method which isn't, from where I've looked, available in Parse for Swift. Right now, what I am doing in order to load up what I have is:
     override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.loadObjects()
        self.loadObjects()
   () }
    }

Comment: This lets me run the load objects in a different thread so I can load at least what I have cached and some of the asynchronous calls that have been completed. From what I understand this is not a complete solution.

Comment: Please edit the question rather than adding massive comments. What result do you get when the objects did load? Any error?

Comment: Sorry about that. When I use the objects did load function and run self.load objects it ends in an infinite loop where its always loading data.

Answer (score 0):

your method as you are using will end up in a never needing cycle

i mean think about about you're asking the app to loadObjects() from parse as soon as the objects finish loading which is the objectsDidLoad()

you are on the right track to call self.loadObjects() to manually load objects
however a more appropriate place to place it is in the viewDidload()